# How to include SQL statements in a C/C++ program?

Tags: c

I want include SQL statements in my C program. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Could anyone please let me know the procedure step by step. 
I am not sure how to establish a connection between the database and my program. Which database do people usually use?

I tried searching in the net but did not get proper solutions. Explanation with a small example is highly appreciated.

Thanks, Rahul

Comment: This is quite platform-dependent.  Some platforms have an embedded SQL pre-processor that takes SQL statements with a particular syntactic wrapper in a program and generates C code that is then compiled.  A number of APIs to do this are available, depending on the platform - some generic like ODBC, some platform specific like OCI.  Can you edit your question to specify what platform you're using?

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not include database functionality in its standard library. I've used [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) before, and I'd highly recommend it as a simple, single-file database to get started with. You can see their [quick start](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) for an idea of how to get things going.

Comment: For the C/C++ API: http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

Answer (score 0):

All major SQL implementations have a C API if you look. Eg:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html

Answer (score 0):

Each database system has a self way to connect a C client program.

If you want use Oracle, look at Oracle Pro*C or http://orclib.sourceforge.net/

If you want use a embedded DB (serveless), look at Oracle Sleepcat or SQLite (very good)

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html

PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/libpq.html

First, choose your DB.
Or, if you don´t want connect with a specific DB, you need add a ODBC API at your project.

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes, I prefer MySQL. But my question is how do I start with. I already have a small DB on MySQL. I want to know how to connect to it using my C program, extract data from it etc...is there a special header that I need to include? a really small example would be very beneficial...thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out [QtSQL](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QtSql.html)